# Value replacement based on other column actual and previous values

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, replace

Is there a way to set to cero the value in column 'result' when current 'obs1' column is 1 and previous 'obs1' column is 0 per ID, omitting loops?

Input Data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2),
     obs1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1),
     obs2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1),
     result1 = c(0,28,63,84,105,135,150,150,150,59, 0,300),
     result2 = c(0,28,63,63,63,63,63,31,59,59,0,0))
```

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
     obs1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1),
     obs2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1),
     result1 = c(0,28,63,84,105,135,150,150,0,59,0,300),
     result2 = c(0,28,63,63,63,63,0,31,59,59,0,0))
```

Changes occur in line 6, 'result2' column and line 9 'result1' column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(result1 = ifelse(obs1==1 & lag(obs1, default = 1) == 0, 0, result1)) %>%
  mutate(result2 = ifelse(obs2==1 & lag(obs2, default = 1) == 0, 0, result2)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

A generic solution can be achieved using `mutate_at` as:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("result")), 
           funs(ifelse( get(sub("result","obs",quo_name(quo(.))))==1 &
                  lag(get(sub("result","obs",quo_name(quo(.)))),
                                             default = 1) ==0  ,0,.)
                                              )) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#    ID obs1 obs2 result1 result2
# 1   1    1    1       0       0
# 2   1    1    1      28      28
# 3   1    1    1      63      63
# 4   1    1    0      84      63
# 5   1    1    0     105      63
# 6   1    1    0     135      63
# 7   1    0    1     150       0
# 8   1    0    1     150      31
# 9   1    1    1       0      59
# 10  1    1    0      59      59
# 11  2    1    0       0       0
# 12  2    1    1     300       0
```

Comment: That definitely works!

However I'm trying to run it under many columns, which relations are like:

obs1 - result1,
ob2 - result2,
obs3 - resul3,
obsn - resultn

Is there any way to do it without writing all the relations?

Comment: @AM.Garcia Ahh okay. I have updated my answer with a generic solution as well. It will use `obs1` for `result1` and `obs2` for `result2` and so on. I have used `mutate_at` with `get`. Have a look.

Comment: Works perfectly